# Swift Calendar Date By Setting Hour To 0 Changes Day

Tags: swift, nsdate

If I run the following code:

```
let date = Date()
let midnight = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .hour, value: 0, of: date)!
let difference = Int64(midnight.timeIntervalSince(date))
print(String(difference))
```

Difference is a positive value of about 13 hours (since the local time is about 11 AM now). However, I would expect that the difference would be negative 11 hours; since I'm setting the `.hour` value to `0` I expect that time would move backward, not forward.

I would expect to have to find midnight tomorrow with this code:

```
let midnight = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .hour, value: 0, of:
   Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!)!
```

But that gives +37 hours instead of +13.

The current behavior is actually the behavior I want (I want to know the time until midnight tomorrow). But, I would like to understand why this is happening, and in particular I want to make sure that this approach of finding midnight tomorrow will work regardless of time zone. Thanks!

EDIT: Note, I only care about the hours until midnight, which is why I don't change the minute or second value when finding midnight.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but note that there is  `Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date)` for this purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is expected as it says in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292915-date),

> The algorithm will try to produce a result which is in the next-larger
>   component to the one given (there’s a table of this mapping at the top
>   of this document). So for the “set to Thursday” example, find the
>   Thursday in the Week in which the given date resides (which could be a
>   forwards or backwards move, and not necessarily the nearest Thursday).
>   For more control over the exact behavior, use
>   nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:behavior:direction:).

Using `nextDate(after date: Date, matching components: DateComponents, matchingPolicy: Calendar.MatchingPolicy, repeatedTimePolicy: Calendar.RepeatedTimePolicy = default, direction: Calendar.SearchDirection = default) -> Date?` yields correct result as you would expect.

Example is here,

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var hourComponent = DateComponents()
hourComponent.hour = 0

let midnightSameDay = calendar.nextDate(after: date,
                                        matching: hourComponent,
                                        matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                                        direction: .backward)
print(mightnightSameDay) // 2018-04-19 00:00:00 +0000

let midnightNextDay = calendar.nextDate(after: date,
                                        matching: hourComponent,
                                        matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                                        direction: .forward)
print(mightnightNextDay) // 2018-04-20 00:00:00 +0000
```

And there is yet another method that you could use for this which uses search direction and matching policy,

```
let midnightSameDay = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 0,
                                    minute: 0,
                                    second: 0,
                                    of: date,
                                    direction: .backward)
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! I used the first example you provided and it works perfectly. I tried the second one as well but it didn't give the correct answer, and per the documentation of that function `The intent is to return a date on the same day as the original date argument. This may result in a date which is backward than the given date, of course.`

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers !

Comment: Please note that the second method probably doesn't work: for me it always created time point at a previous day whether It was .backward or .forward direction. Playing with matchingPolicy made no change either. But the first method did give me full control. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`date(bySetting:value:of)` makes a best guess that is "implementation-defined" towards creating a new `Date` based on the new parameters. By setting the `hour` to `0` - sometimes this will create a `Date` on the same calendar day with the `hour` set accordingly, and sometimes the new `Date` will be tomorrow. It doesn't sound like that will give you the reliability that you need, but hopefully it answers your question.

The docs go further in depth:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292915-date